# How to read whitespace with scanner.next()

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, whitespace

I have a scanner, and have set the delimiter to "", but it still won't read whitespaces with the next() method. I know that nextline() works, but I need to examine every character in the input individually, including whitespace; it's for a complex data analysis problem. I'm stumped, though. Google has turned up nothing.

Can anyone help me with this? I'm thinking of reversing the whitespace into a special character, then for the purposes of analyzing the character, reverse it back into a space, contained in a string... That seems way overkill though! Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

EDIT: My main task is, take a String, and go over it character-by-character, multiple times, to examine the data for various tasks. You will have to examine it many times, one character at a time, and so I thought the scanner class would be my best bet since it can be easy to work with (for me at least). That's my task. Is there an easier way to go about this?

Comment: Are you reading the data from a file or user input?

Comment: Exactly. The function of a scanner is to deliver you tokens and *ignore* the white space. If you need to process every character, you can't use an input mechanism that doesn't give them all to you. It sounds like you need to write yourself a fully fledged scanner of your own as in a hand-written compiler scanner. More details about your problem as opposed to the non-working solution will yield better answers.

Comment: The function of a scanner is to deliver you tokens and IGNORE the delimiter(which is by default `space`).

Comment: Updated with more info on my main task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter("'")
```

But this is highly inefficient. The better way forward would be: to read character by character:

```
private static void readCharacters(Reader reader)
        throws IOException {
    int r;
    while ((r = reader.read()) != -1) {
        char ch = (char) r;
        doSomethingWithChar(ch);
    }
}
```

Also see [HERE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)

Comment: Hey, sorry for not understanding this off the bat, but why is using scanner with a delimiter of "'" any different/better than using it with "" as the delimiter, for the purposes of grabbing whitespace? As well, why is this inefficient?

Answer (score 4):

instead of

```
scanner.next();
```

use

```
scanner.nextLine();
```

This way you solve the problem with delimiters.

Comment: Simple and Best solution!

Answer (score 2):

Try `.useDelimiter("(\\b|\\B)")`

It will use boundaries of every characters as delimiter.

The following code will print exactly what user typed.
No character will be ignored, including whitespaces.

```
Scanner charScanner = new Scanner( System.in ).useDelimiter( "(\\b|\\B)" ) ;
while( charScanner.hasNext() ) 
    System.out.print( charScanner.next() ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `BufferedReader` to read a line of input, then iterate the string in a `for` loop, working with each `char`.
You can check whether a character is a whitespace by `Character.isWhitespace(char c)`.