# Reading Text File in java while preserving white spaces using scanner class

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader, readfile, fileinputstream

I want to read this text file and store the data in a 2D Array. Each white space should be replaced with a `0`, resulting in a final matrix of 0s and 1s. The problem that is occurring is that `Scanner` ignored all the white spaces and put only the 1s in the matrix.

This is text/input file.

```
                                       1111
                                      111111
                                    111 111   1
         111111                    11    111  11
       1111                         111  111    111
       1  1     11111 111           1 11  11        11111
     1111      111                        11111111
       1111     11111             111     1  11 11111
     111 111       1111           111            1111
       111       1111            11111      111111
       111      11 11                11111     111
          1111    11                11111
        1111                            11111
            1111 11 11                      1111
          111     111                        1 111
           11      1111                    111111
         1111      111                    1111
         1111     111                    1111
      1111 11      1111                   1111
        1111  111111                   11111
        111                              11111
          1111                        1111
```

Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new File("D:\Assignment.txt")); int [][] inputMatrix= new int[200][200]; int i=0,j=0; while (fileScanner.hasNextLine()) { String line = fileScanner.nextLine(); Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(line); while (lineScanner.hasNext()) { int token = Integer.parseInt(lineScanner.next()); inputMatrix[i][j]=token; // do whatever needs to be done with token j++; } lineScanner.close(); i++; j=0; // you're at the end of the line here. Do what you have to do. } fileScanner.close();

Comment: share whatever you have tried so that we can find out the problem in your code.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12994342/how-to-read-whitespace-with-scanner-next

Comment: How about readLine() instead of read character per character then replace all spaces for 0 in that line?

Comment: Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new File("D:\\Assignment.txt"));
   int [][] inputMatrix= new int[200][200];
   int i=0,j=0;
   while (fileScanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = fileScanner.nextLine();
    Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(line);
    while (lineScanner.hasNext()) {
     int token = Integer.parseInt(lineScanner.next());
     inputMatrix[i][j]=token;
      // do whatever needs to be done with token
      j++;
    }
    lineScanner.close();
    i++;
    j=0;
    // you're at the end of the line here. Do what you have to do.
   }
   fileScanner.close();

Comment: @user3678399 Please do not add code as a comment, it's completely unreadable. Edit your post, add and format it there.

Answer (score 2):

Read the lines and convert them to a 2D array:

```
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("array.txt"));
while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
    lines.add(sc.nextLine());
}

// to array
int rows = lines.size();              // number of rows
int cols = 0;                         // number of columns
for(String line : lines) {
    cols = Math.max(cols, line.length());
}
int[][] array = new int[rows][cols];  // full of 0s
int i = 0;
for(String line : lines) {            // for each line, add the 1s
    char[] chars = line.toCharArray();
    for(int j = 0 ; j < chars.length ; ++j) {
        if(chars[j] == '1') {
            array[i][j] = 1;
        }
    }
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
String input = "";
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    input += sc.nextLine()+"\n";
}
sc.close();
String[] array = input.split("\n");
```

now you have an array of lines, you can use `replace(" ", "0")` on each string and then `toCharArray()` to create an array of chars and put them all in a new array

Comment: Doesn't hasNextLine() return boolean?

Comment: Still is the wrong check on Scanner since it throws `NoSuchElementException` - if no line was found