# Reading in line with blank space at end using java scanner class

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm helping my sisters with a simple java program and I'm stumped. They've only learned scanner classes to read file contents, so I think they're supposed to use the scanner class. Each line contains letters and potentially a blank space, and we're hoping to store each line in an array. This works fine and dandy until one of the lines contains something like:

> abcde f (the blank space after f should be read in as part of the
>   line).

However, `scanner.nextLine()` seems to disregard this last blank space. I figured I could set my scanner delimiter to `\n` like so:

```
scanner.useDelimiter("\n")
```

and then use `scanner.Next()` from there, but this still doesn't seem to work. I've googled around and taken a look at a few stackoverflow questions. This question here seems to suggest this is not easily done with the scanner class: [How to read whitespace with scanner.next()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12994342/how-to-read-whitespace-with-scanner-next)

Any ideas?  I feel like there's an easy way I'm overlooking.

This is how I'm reading in the lines:

```
While(scanner.hasNextLine(){
    String nextLine = scanner.nextLine();
```

Using the above example, my string would read `abcde f`. It will get rid of the empty space at the end.
I've also tried to use `hasNext` and `next`.
Pardon my formatting, I'm editing on a phone.

Comment: Show the part that reads each line. Make sure not to use any [trim()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim())

Comment: Verify the content to make sure what characters are there in each line of the file using Notepad++ which is able to show all non-printed characters graphically using "show all characters" feature from the menu bar. Make sure the file encoding is correct from the original source as different file encoding can be a problem when reading a file (UTF-8, ASCII, etc.)

Comment: Will do in a bit, thanks. What am I looking for, that the blank space shows up? I'm not sure its the files problem because the files we read in are provided to test with.

Comment: Just to verify the space that you are looking for occurs right after the  [linefeed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) (CRLF, \r\n or /0x0d /0x10 for Windows system) or before it.

Comment: I see LF in places of the blank space at the end of my line. From a quick google search, it seems that \n matches this.

Comment: Did you see `abcde{SPACE}f{SPACE}{LF}` or `abcde{SPACE}f{LF}`?

Comment: I see the latter, where the space is completely replaced with LF. When I manually enter a space between f and LF, it works. However, this is a provided input file so I don't know if I can modify it as part of the final solution.

Answer (score 3):

Save your text file as ANSI encoding and try again.

By right `scanner.nextLine()` will capture everything in the line, including whitespace.

`scanner.next()` will not capture whitespace as the delimiter is *whitespace* by default.